# Getting most busy employee from the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models:

```
# Table name: work_schedules
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  start_time  :time             not null
#  end_time    :time             not null
#  day_of_week :string           not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  person_id   :integer

# Table name: people
#
#  id                         :integer          not null, primary key
#  pesel                      :string           not null
#  first_name                 :string           not null
#  last_name                  :string           not null
```

I want to get the most busy employee in query.
First I should count hours(end_time - start_time) and count day_of_week(unique attribute scope: person_id). I don't have any idea how to create properly query this.
What I tried:

```
@most_busy = Person.joins(:work_schedules).where(%q{end_time - start_time}).first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all days of the week (i.e., summing across all days of the week):
`WorkSchedule.group(:person_id).sum('extract(epoch from work_schedules.end_time) -extract(epoch from work_schedules.start_time)').sort_by { |_,v| -v}.first.first`

This will give you the ID of the Person who has worked the most over all WorkSchedules. I've only tested it with PostgreSQL.

What's going on in this query:

1. Get all the work schedule objects and group them by person ids
2. For each of these groups of work schedules, get the sum of the differences between the start and end times. The extract epoch from tells SQL to get the timestamps as integers (UNIX timestamps, I believe). It is necessary because otherwise the result of the query gives these sums as strings such as "17 days 136:57:42.748124" which ruby cannot sort correctly.
3. The SQL query results in hash of the form {person_id: time_scheduled_in_seconds}.
4. The sort_by sorts the query in reverse of the values. We aren't using the keys from the hash so we use an underscore rather than a name to ignore them.
5. Then we take the first item in this hash (hence the first ".first").
6. Since that actually returns an array with the person_id as the first value and the number of seconds as the second value, we keep only the first item (hence the second ".first")

Comment: I should also count days and for each time. For example when one work three times a week another can work more...

Comment: So you want the employee who has worked the most over the last week? Or an arbitrary week you specify?

Comment: I want count hours per week for each person and get who has the most. All weeks are same. E.G When I specify that person_id: 1 start_time: 8:00 end_time: 12:00 day_of_week: monday. This applies to every week.

Comment: could you explain me what is here? I want understand.

Comment: Added some explanation. Let me know if anything needs clarification. I know it's definitely not the prettiest ActiveRecord query in the world, but I think it works.